# Error Trying to get Property non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have model
User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
protected $table = "users";
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function product()
{
    return ProductModel::where('iduser', $this->id)->get();
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductModel');
}

public function prepaid()
{
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\PrepaidModel');
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\PrepaidModel');
    return PrepaidModel::where('iduser', $this->id)->get();
}
}
```

i want show data from table with relation here order.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Order History || <a href="home">Back</a> to Dashboard</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="order">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-5 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Order" class="form-control">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" placeholder="Search Order" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" class="form-control">
                                    <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>


                       <table class="table">
                           <tr>
                               <td>Order Number</td>
                               <td>Description</td>
                               <td>Total</td>
                               <td>Information</td>
                           </tr>

                           @foreach($User as $item)
                               <tr>
                                   <td>{{$item -> product()}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$item -> description}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$item -> total}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$item -> information}}</td>

                               </tr>
                           @endforeach
                       </table>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

file ProductModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "product";
    protected $fillable = ['idproduct', 'iduser', 'name_product', 'address', 'price', 'total', 'description', 'information'];


}
```

the problem is, when I use this in function in ProductModel I get all data:

```
return ProductModel::where('iduser', $this->id)->get();
```

but when I'm trying to get selected field like this:

```
return ProductModel::where('iduser', $this->id)->first()->id;
```

I get error like this

> ErrorException, trying to get property of non-object

so I'm trying to use belongsTo like this in function product in file Product Model.php

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductModel');
```

then in order.blade I change

```
$item -> product -> id
```

I get same error with

> ErrorException, trying to get property of non-object

what I miss? I am follow any tutorial, that same way but it not work for me

here my field on table user
[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW3Dd.png)
and field on table product
[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aM2l.png)

Comment: The error says there is not product with `iduser = $this->id` in the table.

Comment: $this -> id = thats mean field id in this class right ?
ProductModel:: is model then mention where('iduser') for field iduser in ProductModel ?

Comment: This exception is caused by when you try to get the some property of a `null`.  Just `dd` your results and verify what you are getting.

Comment: can i get custom field with method get() ? without this [{}]

Comment: what do you mean by custom field ?

Comment: like select just field id in database not all, because with get() all data show like this [{id:123123,Iduser:1}], i want to get one of them like just id

Comment: Yes you  can use `pluck` method like this `ProductModel::where('userId', $this->id)->pluck('prod_description')` . In this case you will get `prod_description` column

Comment: its work, but i just get 1 data, how to get all data ? with pluck() i get just first on row

Comment: You can try this `ProductModel::where('userId', $this->id)->pluck('prod_description')->first()`

Comment: What you actually want ?

Comment: all data in product table, with first() or pluck() i just get 1 data from product table

Comment: `ProductModel::all()->pluck('prod_description')` . This will give you prod_description column for all records within product table.

Comment: thanks, that work :)